# Weird id() behaviour; different ids, yet id(x) == id(y) returns True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, identity

I created a dummy class with two empty methods:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass
    def baz(self):
        pass
```

When I create an instance `foo` of my `Foo` class, why is `id(foo.bar) == id(foo.baz)` True even though the ids are obviously different?

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> id(foo.bar)
31344648
>>> id(foo.baz)
35951432
>>> id(foo.bar) == id(foo.baz)
True
```

However, using a function like this:

```
def is2(obj1, obj2):
    return id(obj1) == id(obj2)
```

The two methods' ids are no longer equal:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> is2(foo.bar, foo.baz)
False
```

Comment: Methods are created on demand and ids can be reused.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But as you can see from the second piece of code, `id(foo.bar) == 31344648` and `id(foo.baz) == 35951432`, which are obviously not equal? Does the id suddenly change when I access two methods at once?

Comment: The `id()` changes **all the time**. Run `id(foo.bar)` a few times in succession. Create a few other objects. Test again. Use `foo.bar is foo.baz` and see they are not the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are wrappers that are re-created on demand. Each time you refer to `foo.baz` a *new* method object is created.

Next, memory locations can be reused; `id()` values are only unique for the lifetime of an object. When the object no longer is needed (the reference count drops to 0) Python removes that object and is free to re-use the same memory space.

By doing `id(foo.bar)` the new method object only lives for the duration of the `id()` call. The next `id(foo.baz)` call is then free to reuse that memory location, and your `==` equality test returns true, purely because Python is being economic with memory allocation.

That the memory locations were not equal when you were testing the methods on separate lines is as much a coincidence that they were equal in the equality test. Neither is a given. Other objects are created in the interpreter at different stages and can end up reusing a memory location before the next method object is created, for example

Comment: Alright thanks! Mind explaining the last part, my `is2()` function? `id(foo.bar) == id(foo.baz), is2(foo.bar, foo.baz)` returns `(True, False)` **Edit:** Nvm, I got it! They're function arguments and thus kept after the `id()` function's call.